# Analytical strategies for relative velocity problems

Tags: optimization, classical-mechanics

A cyclist P is cycling due north at a constant speed of $u$ m/s. Another cyclist Q
is due west of P. The speed of Q is constant at $v$ m/s. Find the angle $\theta$ to from east to which $Q$ should travel to minimise the closest distance between $P$ and $Q$

Relative velocity problems in similar settings are very common. I am quite a fan of analytical approaches to mechanics, but when it comes to relative velocity, geometric approaches just seem to crush calculus. This problem can be computed in a single line with geometric considerations. I doubt an analytical approach could do this will, but I'm looking for something that evens the playing field.

My current approach would be to formulate the problem in terms of vectors, where $v_p=(u\cos\theta, u\sin\theta), v_q=(0,v)$ hence we have the relative distance $D$, $D^2=||x_p - x_q||=(ut\cos\theta+d)^2+(ut\sin\theta - vt)^2$. From here we take two partials, one with respect to $t$ to find the $t=T$ at which $D$ is minimum. With this we then minimise with respect to $\theta$ and obtain the answer. This arduous exercise takes no less than fifteen minutes.

I am looking for a good analytical approach to relative velocities in general, but use the given problem as an example to prevent the question being too broad. Most of these problems have the same idea, so I'm hoping there is a quick catch all strategy like the geometers have, rather than only solving this problem.

Comment: Is the initial distance between $P$ and $Q$ known ?

Comment: I think you can greatly reduce the calculations, if you consider the problem in the frame of $P$ or $Q$. Find the relative velocity of $P$ wrt $Q$. It should be something like $(u-v\cos\theta,v\sin\theta)$. In $Q$ frame, the path of $P$ looks just like a straight line, so the shortest distance can be found by finding the perpendicular distance of that line to $Q$. Then differentiate this distance wrt to $\theta$ and that should give you the optimal value of $\theta$.

Comment: @RohanNuckchady In this problem the distance is not needed, but it may well be in other problems. I have found frames of references in relative velocity not to be of much help, generally all it means is that terms have been subtracted onto the other side of an equation and the rest remains the same. Now that I think again, you are right, I don't think I need to minimise T, only theta is needed. I am still interested in what alternatives there are, I was hoping there would be a good variational approach